# How can I get the session values from an external.js by using Struts2 jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, session, struts2

I need to recover a value from session in my external JS. Before, I did it in a script embedded in the JSP with this lines and it worked properly:

```javascript
$(window).load(function(){
    var selectedServer = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedServer}'/>";
    var selectedMarket = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedMarket}'/>";
});
```

but now, I want to do it from an external JS and an `alert(selectedServer);` after these lines, show me the literal: `<s:property value='%{#session.selectedServer}'/>`, but not the value.

Is the syntax different in an `external.js`?

Comment: No! you can have a session values in external js, you can have this on jsp page where you have loaded all your files and pass it on just as your are doing currently.

Comment: Thank for the response @Jai, do you mean it?                                         <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
    var selectedServer = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedServer}'/>";
    var selectedMarket = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedMarket}'/>";
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>

Comment: Yes! This is the way i see people pass on the session var values.

Comment: as you know jsp java runs on serverside and javascript is a clientside language and this runs in browser, so session vars has been set at serverside so that is why you donot have those values in the js files because at that point of time the jsp has not been loaded in the browser.

Comment: @Jai Good explanation, lesson learned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript global variables in the external script, or use function parameters to pass the values that you should obtain in the JSP to the external function.

```jsp
<script>
    var selectedServer = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedServer}'/>";
    var selectedMarket = "<s:property value='%{#session.selectedMarket}'/>";
</script>
```

```javascript
function(selectedServer, selectedMarket){
}
```